# REGEX : get a text in middle of string and number

Tags: regex

The problem I am facing is that if I have this string:

```
STARTGAME grindurr 9 51 19 3 7 1 2 2 0
```

...I want to extract name `grindurr` from the middle.  I tried this regex:

```
STARTGAME\t.*\t[^\d]
```

...but it didn't work. :(  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @loldop: I don't think nsregularexpressions support indefinite-length lookbehind assertions.

Comment: @TimPietzcker so, use without this: `\w+\s+(\w+)\s+(?=\d+)`

Comment: @RVector, are you really using the NSRegularExpression class from Apple's Objective-C framework?  Because that's what that tag means.  Please update your question and either reaffirm the `nsregularexpression` tag or replace it with the tag for whichever flavor you *are* using (`c#`, `javascript`, `sed`, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
STARTGAME\s+(.*?)\s+\d
```

might work. The result is then in the first capturing group. You can remove the need for the capturing group by using lookaround, but I don't know the exact capabilities by that regex engine, so above is probably the safest way.

Comment: Great minds think alike, it seems. Although your solution is a bit cleverer than @alex's :)

Comment: It's kind of obvious, I guess ;). And the only thing I did was not to include a quantifier for the `\d` at the end because it's only needed as a delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use...

```
STARTGAME\s+(.*?)\s+\d+
```

That should have the word between `STARTGAME` and the first number.